# Enviar json a traves de ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

Eh visto documentos y esta es la forma en la que entiendo para enviar datos.
Y la cosa es que no me toma ningún dato al momento de precionar el boton.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-5" value="Confirmar nota de venta" id="todo_bien">Confirmar</button>
   
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#todo_bien").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '?&page=retail/actions/egg',
                data: miJSON,
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function(){
                    alert("Ha sido ejecutada la acción.");
                },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                    console.log("ERROR" + errorMessage + textStatus + xhr);
                }
            });
            
        });
    });
```

Lo que estoy enviando es un array lo cual lo convertí en un json.

```
$miJSON = json_encode($outputarray);
```

No se si esta sea la manera correcta .

Comment: La variable miJSON que envías en `data: miJSON,` no aparece definida en ningún lado. Lo normal es generar esa variable con datos de un formulario, de elementos de la página, o de algún sitio, en tu código no especificas qué es `miJSON`, por lo que lo normal es que no envíe nada.

Comment: Gracias igual. Tuve que traspasar en un var la variable de php también. Simplemente asignándole la variable del php por defecto /////let Myjsonpana = <?= $miJSON ?>;////////////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el elemento data puede ser:
[PlainObject or String or Array](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

si tratas de mandar un json, no lo enviará, la conversión a JSON la hace el dataType el cual ya tienes definido

asi que seria: `$miJSON = $outputarray;`

Debemos siempre ir a la [documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)